# mPDF error: Unable to create output file: cache/Invoice.pdf

Tags: php

I am facing one problem on vtiger crm

Error message is:
**mPDF error: Unable to create output file: cache/Invoice.pdf**

```
case 'F':
        //Save to local file
        $f=fopen($name,'wb');
        if(!$f) $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
        fwrite($f,$this->buffer,strlen($this->buffer));
        fclose($f);
        break;
```

Comment: Show your code please and exact line number will be pointed where error occur

Comment: case 'F': {
     // Save PDF to a local file
     if ($this->diskcache) {
      copy($this->buffer, $name);
     } else {
      $f = fopen($name, 'wb');
      if (!$f) {
       $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
      }
      fwrite($f, $this->getBuffer(), $this->bufferlen);
      fclose($f);
     }
     break;
    }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Learn How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: give php the write permissions of the directory

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have permissions to create file. Try specifying full path till file, like `$fileName = "/var/app/public_html/cache/Invoice.pdf"`

Why are you using PHP way to save file that mPDF generates? Why not using `Output($fileName, $destinationType)`

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hallo World</p>');
$mpdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
```

[Documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125).

Answer (score 0):

make sure that file **cache/Invoice.pdf** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.